# What do the feature importance numbers mean when doing elastic net feature importance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I have written some code that does some feature ranking in a dataset I have. And the result is a plot with the x-axis values being the names of the features and the y-values being numbers that go from 0 to 0.7

What do these specific numbers mean or represent? How do I interpret these as feature importance?

Here is a picture of the plot. I have added the 'Rank Weight' titles on the y-axis.[image]

Comment: Hi Nic.o, since you have not added any details regarding `code that does some feature ranking`, its impossible to know what these represent and how they are computed. Please add the code for the same. Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for StackOverflow. This appears to be asking: "*How do I interpret the coefficients of a linear model?*" which is more of a stats question than a programming question.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I have posted the code in this other question I made about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940668/create-dataframe-out-of-plot-of-feature-rank-importance).  I will also ask this question the stats overflow